# Schema.org - How to present Statistical data in markup

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

I have a website where I visualize statistical data with geoJSON. The description of a statistic e.g. is `Graduation ratio of primary education`
and the data looks smth. like:

```
features: [
{
    geometry: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: Array(1)}
    properties: {name: "Afghanistan", id: "AF", value: 64, latitude: 33, longitude: 65, …}
    type: "Feature"
},
{
    geometry: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: Array(1)}
    properties: {name: "Albania", id: "AL", value: 98, latitude: 41, longitude: 20, …}
    type: "Feature"
}
]
```

My question is now on how could I represent this data best with schema.org. There are 2 types which I feel like could come close to it:

- https://schema.org/Observation
- https://schema.org/Dataset

I went with the dataSet approach and the markup looks to smth like this:

```
@context: "http://schema.org"
@type: "Dataset"
creator: {@type: "Organization", url: "...", name: "Eduinsights", contactPoint: {…}}
description: "Global visualization for educational statistics/observations provided by UNESCO: Graduation ratio of primary education,Net enrolment rate for primary education,Percentage of female repeaters primary education,Percentage of qualified teachers secondary education,Proportion of primary schools with access to internet for pedagogical purposes"
keywords: ["Statistics > education > Graduation ratio of primary education", "Statistics > education > Net enrolment rate for primary education", "Statistics > education > Percentage of female repeaters primary education", "Statistics > education > Percentage of qualified teachers secondary education", "Statistics > education > Proportion of primary sch… with access to internet for pedagogical purposes"]
name: "Educational statistics"
spatialCoverage: {@type: "Place", geo: {…}}
temporalCoverage: "Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:02 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)/Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:02 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)"
url: "..."
```

Is this really the right way to go? There are not much sources online about schema.org representation of statistical data.

Comment: Please deleted [your post at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65555733/schema-org-how-to-present-statistical-data-in-markup) as [cross-posting is not allowed](/meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) and this question is a better fit here.

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:seo] but finding some schema to apply doesn't help your SEO.  See [SEO Myth: Structured data helps search engine rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/structured-data-seo/).  The only way schema helps is when you get a rich snippet in the Google search results.   As far as I know, there is no rich snippet for data sets.

Comment: Love the reference of your blog post. :D However I would like to provide a rich snippets that looks smth like a table/diagram - and that visualization shows the observations values of my data. I know it does not have a direct impact on boosting the seo ranking. But when User click on the rich-snippets - this can do!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller While to an extent I'm sympathetic to your views on mythology in SEO, Google's Search Advocate has [stated](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/980902538865205248) that structured data helps Google to better understand and classify pages. It also has uses beyond Google and beyond SEO. I'm not sure it's accurate or helpful to dismiss it completely. Also, there are in fact [rich results for datasets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset).

Comment: @GDVS thanks for pointing out the rich result for datasets, maybe put that in as an answer?   I have seen very limited usage of structured data beyond Google rich results.   Mostly I've seen scrapers use it to easily take your data and republish it in a different format.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is your goal in using structured data?

From an SEO perspective, the primary use case is to trigger enriched search snippets or, to an increasing degree, provide access to interactions and other enhanced functionality for voice search (see Google's [Guided Recipes](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/recipe), example).

Google [does currently have a Dataset feature](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset) that uses structured data, but the fact you don't mention it in your question suggests it's either not what you're after, or you haven't found it in your research.

But there are of course potential applications beyond traditional SEO, especially with JSON-LD, in that you can make data accessible to virtually any application that's interested in consuming it, in a nice, standardised format. The access to interactions noted above, for instance, gets us into providing functionality for intelligent assistants like Google Assistant, some mail and calendar applications, etc.

Clarifying your objective in providing structured data should get you a long way towards figuring out which approach is best for you. If it's SEO, you're constrained by what's supported by the search engines your target audience uses. If it's broader than that, you have more options and what search engines do or do not support may be less important.